# How do I set encoding with NSURLConnection/NSData/String?

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I'm using an API that's returning data with some encoding problems. In Firefox, special characters display properly, such as the word "ombré." In Safari—and, in the response from an NSURLConnection—that word comes in as "ombrÃ©." I'm then displaying this content in UILabels in my app. How do I deal with the encoding issues? If I force Safari into UTF-8, the special characters appear properly, how do I do the same from NSURLConnection or the NSData returned?

Answer (score 0):

Use this initializer/constructor 
`- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data
                    encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

Comment: Tried doing this in a backwards way, but the data goes through NSJSONSerialization though, which requires NSData, so I tried going from the encodedString back to NSData to then pass into JSONSer, but it didn't work.

Comment: It's been a month and maybe you fixed it but if you still have problems I would glad to try helping. Can you post some actual code?